# Save last {{!loop}} value in iMacro script after error

Tags: imacros

I am running an iMacro script in the free FF Extension format.

This Macro runs all night in a loop and uses the `{{!LOOP}}` variable. During the night the script might crash and when it does I need a way to see at whatvalue of `{{!LOOP}}` the script crashed in order to pick off at that part.

How can I save the last `{{!loop}}` value in iMacro script even after an error?

Comment: You can also use 'SET !ERRORIGNORE YES' in order to to keep looping even when encountering an error. If your code logic allows you.

Comment: Is ok. I want it to fail because I don't want there to be gaps for certain loop values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following code to update the url on the next tab to be !LOOP so when it crashes the value there is exactly what you need. You need the 2nd tab to already be open. **This method is very quick!**

```
TAB T=1
'your code goes here

'don't wanna wait long
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1 
'don't crash because http://1 doesn't exist
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES 
'go to next tab - notice this tab has to already be open
TAB T=2  
'update url in tab
URL GOTO={{!LOOP}}  
'return to original tab
TAB T=1  
'timeout back to normal
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60  
'continue failing on error like in default
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

You can also save to disk for **more reliability** and tracking of individual loops that failed if you want to continue even when failing.

Comment: Works great. What will happen if I dont have tab2 open?

Comment: In that case `URL GOTO={{!LOOP}}` will override your current tabs' url. If you put this code at the end of your code worst case it wont save the url, you dont need to worry about harming your other code or causing crashes.

Answer (score 2):

expending the answer above me you can use your macro just go to url's like : `URL GOTO=www.yoururl.com/?nothing={{!LOOP}}`

by adding `?nothing={{!LOOP}}` most sites won't be affected but the result is the same as opening a new tab to {{!LOOP}} without the new tab